# How do big bundled open source projects like Spring Boot ensure compatibility between modules?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, release, release-management

Spring Boot contains loads of dependencies: Spring Framework, Spring Data, etc. How do the Spring maintainers accomplish releasing everything while different teams work on different Spring projects?

We have a similar situation, we have 4-5 teams each making different libraries which are used by other teams. We prefer to be able to allow teams to release independently but this is a huge undertaking to ensure binary compatibility of interface and behaviour.

Comment: It seems you are looking for a general answer, but you might get some specific help for your situation if you provide specifics about your technical stack.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each release of Spring Boot provides a curated list of dependencies it supports. In practice, you do not need to provide a version for any of these dependencies in your build configuration as Spring Boot is managing that for you. When you upgrade Spring Boot itself, these dependencies will be upgraded as well in a consistent way.

The curated list contains all the spring modules that you can use with Spring Boot as well as a refined list of third party libraries. The list is available as a standard Bills of Materials (spring-boot-dependencies) and additional dedicated support for Maven and Gradle are available as well.

URL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html